# CI form validation with callback

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, callback

I'am creating change password using CI form validation and set rules with callback to the model.

```
public function change_password()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('current_password', 'Current Password', 'trim|required|callback_change');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_password', 'New Password', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_lenght[10]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_new_password', 'Confirm New Password', 'trim|required|matches[new_password]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
    {
        $this->load->view('change_pass');
    }
}
```

this is the callback function for check the password and then change the password:

```
function change()
{
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $username = $session_data['username'];
    $this->User_model->check_pass($username);
    $rst = $this->User_model->check_pass($username);

    foreach ($rst as $row) 
    {
        $db_password = $row->password;
    }

    if (md5($this->input->post('current_password')) == $db_password) 
    {
        //model for change password here

        $this->form_validation->set_message('change', 'Change Password Success');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('change', 'Wrong current password');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

this is the change password form

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('inspection/changepassword'); ?>
Current Password : <input type="password" name="old_password"><br>
New Password : <input type="password" name="new_password"><br>
New Password Conf : <input type="password" name="conf_new_password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Change Password">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Form validation only working when current password is false or if all the field in the form is empty, but if the current password is true or match with the database form validation doesn't run false eventhough new password and confirmation new password not match. Please help me to fix it, I'am sorry if my English or my question is not clear. Thanks very much

Comment: what are "the other rules"?

Comment: Just a tip don't use md5 for passwords very easy to hack these days use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Vickel the other rules are new_password and conf_new_password, if both not match form validation should be run false right?